# Add new key:value pairs to existing an existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here's my existing data:

```
var nodes = [
    {i: 0, radius: 18.637872483796723},
    {i: 0, radius: 17.174333481950903},
    {i: 0, radius: 13.194447610161163},
    {i: 1, radius: 8.000718059188364},
    {i: 1, radius: 4.08204211857112}
  ];
```

I need to add one new key:value pairs for each item in the list. It is dynamically calculated:

```
cx: i*2
```

So the new array would look like this:

```
[
  {i: 0, radius: 18.637872483796723, cx: 0},
  {i: 0, radius: 17.174333481950903, cx: 0},
  {i: 0, radius: 13.194447610161163, cx: 0},
  {i: 1, radius: 8.000718059188364, cx: 2},
  {i: 1, radius: 4.08204211857112, cx: 2}
];
```

I am a beginner, so excuse any terminology that I've butchered (I'm not sure if I'm using the term array correctly).

Comment: Regarding terminology, you have an array of objects and want add a new property to each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nodes.forEach(function(n) {n.cx = n.i * 2});
```

Comment: For support in browsers made when the wooly mammoths were wandering the earth, there's always [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and a similar thing in Underscore.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i=0; i<nodes.lenght;i++)
    nodes[i].cx = i*2;
```

Comment: yes nodes var is define in question .  
var nodes = [
    {i: 0, radius: 18.637872483796723},
    {i: 0, radius: 17.174333481950903},
    {i: 0, radius: 13.194447610161163},
    {i: 1, radius: 8.000718059188364},
    {i: 1, radius: 4.08204211857112}
  ];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea